# Calculate sum of 2-D list

Tags: python, list

I need to find the sum of 2-D List, but i am only able to find the sum of the first list. Can someone please point me or guide me, and also i see people using counter. We are not allowed to use counter.

```
def avg(lst):
i = 0 
A = 0 
for item in lst :
   B = lst[i][A]+lst[i][A+1]+lst[i][A+2]
i = i +1
return B
```

i have this as the list value

```
lsit = [[95, 92, 86], [66, 75, 54], [89, 72, 100], [34, 0, 0]]
```

when i execute i am only getting the sum of the first list but i need to get the sum of whole list.

```
In [55]: avg(lsit)
Out[55]: 273
```

Comment: add some spaces in the line i=i+1 so it's part of the for loop. Also B should be adding to itself (B = B + ...).

Comment: `reduce(lambda x, y: x + sum(y),list, 0)` a handy one-liner that will do the job, but yes as other have pointed out the problem is in your indentation.

Answer (score 1):

I have done a few minimal changes to your code. Follow the comments

```
def avg(lst): 
    i = 0 
    A = 0 
    B = 0                                          # initialize
    for item in lst :
       B += lst[i][A]+lst[i][A+1]+lst[i][A+2]      # Use +=
       i = i +1                                    # Inside loop
    return B
```

An alternative using builtin `sum` and gen-exp is

```
>>> lsit = [[95, 92, 86], [66, 75, 54], [89, 72, 100], [34, 0, 0]]
>>> sum(sum(i) for i in lsit)
763
```

---

<sub>Do note that you are using `avg` to find *sum*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

flatten lists and use sum

```
lsit = [[95, 92, 86], [66, 75, 54], [89, 72, 100], [34, 0, 0]]
print(sum( x for sublist in lsit for x in sublist ))
```

Output

```
763
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to get the sum of every element in lsit?  This does it...

```
import numpy as np
lsit = [[95, 92, 86], [66, 75, 54], [89, 72, 100], [34, 0, 0]]
np.sum(lsit)
```